# React Navigation with Async Storage React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, asyncstorage

I have been trying to find resources/code to help me but I've come up stuck. I currently save a users Auth token if they logged in into Async Storage. In my App.js where the app gets loaded I call Async Storage.getItem() and if the token isn't null I want them to go to the home screen but if it is null go to my welcome screen. Im having trouble setting up the navigator aspect.

App.js

```
import Navigator from "./homeStack";

export default function App() {
  const [isLogedin, setIsLogedin] = useState(false);
  const readData = async () => {
    try {
      let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
      if (token != null) {
        setIsLogedin(true);
        //Navigate to the home screen
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("read data error" + e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    readData();
  }, []);

  return <Navigator />;
}
```

Navigator component

```
const screens = {
  welcome: {
    screen: welcome,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
 
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: homeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
};

const homeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

export default createAppContainer(homeStack);
```

what am i missing/ how do i fix my code? By default it starts up with the welcome screen, but if the user already signed in go to the home screen.

Comment: Can not see how you are saving the session values. But you can compare your Async Storage code from [here](https://fluttertpoint.com/async-storage-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

Heres a [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) on how you do it from react-native-navigation itself.

Comment: it only shows how to do it in Functional components but not class components.